# Achieve new BigInteger(130, new SecureRandom()).toString(32) in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, secure-random

I understand that we can use `window.crypto` to generate a secure random number, however `window.crypto.getRandomValues()` is using `typedArray`.
May I know how can we achieve exactly this Java function in JavaScript:

```
new BigInteger(130, new SecureRandom()).toString(32)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could generate four 32-bit numbers for a total of 128 - close to your Java maximum of 130 (the value specified to the constructor of `BigInteger` is the **maximum** number of bits, as stated in the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#BigInteger(int,%20java.util.Random))), then convert them all to base 32, and finally join them together.

```
function getSecureRandom() {
    // allocate space for four 32-bit numbers
    const randoms = new Uint32Array(4);
    // get random values
    window.crypto.getRandomValues(randoms);
    // convert each number to string in base 32, then join together
    return Array.from(randoms).map(elem => elem.toString(32)).join("");
}
```

The [`Array#from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) call is necessary because `TypedArray.prototype.map` returns another `TypedArray`, and a typed array cannot contain strings. We first convert the typed array `randoms` into a normal array, then call `.map()` on it.